# C++ Visual Studio 2013 compile error?

Tags: c++

I'm really confused on what I'm doing wrong in my code. Here is a screenshot for you: http://prntscr.com/74z4r7

Error Code:

> Error 7   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'K:munichscrypteruilderincludelibeay32MT.lib'   c:\Users\gaming\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\CPlusPlusCrypter\CPlusPlusCrypter\LINK    CPlusPlusCrypter

Comment: Copy the error message as text, [edit] your question, and put it **here**, in the question itself. There is absolutely no reason to use an image to provide a compiler error - if you can't figure out how to copy/paste it, *carefully* type it. With the majority of the content somewhere else, this question has no value to future readers if that off-site content is unavailable. In  addition to having to leave this site to see what you're asking, even if the image is embedded here it's hard to read from mobile devices, and it's inconsiderate to users with limited bandwidth or who pay for data.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need double `\` in your file path. 
In other words, replace all of the `\` with `\\`.

Comment: Awesome! Please mark my answer as 'accepted' so that anyone with a similar problem can easily see the solution.